# make C^1 function which satisfying following

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $E$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ let $K=E^c$

then $f(x)=d(x,K)=\inf_{y\in K}d(x,y)$ is function s.t

(i) if $x \in E$, $f(x)=d(x,K)>0$

(ii) if $x \in K$ ,$f(x)=d(x,K)=0$

$f(x)$ is not $C^1$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ generally. (if we let $E=(0,1)\subset \mathbb{R}$ then f(x) is not differentiable at 0,1,1/2)

I want to show the existence of $C^1$ function $g(x) $on $\mathbb{R}^n$ s.t

(i) $g(x)\leq d(x,K),\forall x \in$ $\mathbb{R}^n$

(ii)$\forall x \in E, g(x)>0$

How can I start this proof.